# Do import libs and include files have 32bit and 64bit versions?

Tags: c, openssl, include, 64-bit, import-libraries

I know an 64 bit application cannot load 32bit dlls, but when I compile the application, should I use a 64bit version of include file and a 64 bit version of lib to link?

Specifically, if I build a 64 bit program using openssl, should I download a 64bit version of include files and lib files for openssl? Or, the include files and lib files are the same for 32bit and 64bit, just the openssl dlls are different?

Comment: No go. Even if that was possible in the general sense, the declarations in the header files would be different and thus incompatible if they used `int` instead of `int32_t`, etc.

Comment: Projects normally try to minimize the number of different headers, even if there are some differences when compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit software.  So often, but not necessarily, headers are neutral — but sometimes they need configuration information.  The libraries definitely are different for 32-bit and 64-bit.